# More efficient way to get averages from data frame in R and save them back to same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Using the `plyr` library for R, I can get the average of different measurements for the same variable stored in a data frame in R, like this:

```
library(plyr)
dataAvg <- ddply(data, .(VOWEL_QUALITIES), summarise, PITCH = mean(PITCH))
```

where the data frame is, for example, like this:

```
VOWEL_QUALITIES <- c(rep("a",3),rep("i",3))
TOKEN <- c("Measurement 1", "Measurement 2", "Measurement 3", "Measurement 1", "Measurement 2", "Measurement 3")
PITCH <- c(10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17)
data <- data.frame(VOWEL_QUALITIES, PITCH, TOKEN)
```

After getting these averages, I can add a "TOKEN" column to the "dataAvg" data frame and `rbind()` it back to the "data" data frame, if, for example, I want to plot the pitch of each vowel for each measurement *in addition to its average*:

```
dataAvg$TOKEN <- c(rep("Average",7))
data <- rbind(data,dataAvg)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, where I don't have to manually add an extra column to the data frame with the averages and then manually `rbind()` it back to the main data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in one step?

```
rbind(
 data,
 ddply(data, .(VOWEL_QUALITIES), summarise, PITCH = mean(PITCH), TOKEN="Average")
)
```

Result:

```
  VOWEL_QUALITIES PITCH         TOKEN
1               a    10 Measurement 1
2               a    11 Measurement 2
3               a    12 Measurement 3
4               i    15 Measurement 1
5               i    16 Measurement 2
6               i    17 Measurement 3
7               a    11       Average
8               i    16       Average
```

Comment: Ah, well I should have been able to figure that out on my own ... Ha. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use data.table's `:=` to put it inline:

```
require(data.table)
data = data.table(data)
data[,AVG:=mean(PITCH),by="VOWEL_QUALITIES"]
```

Then data is:

```
  VOWEL_QUALITIES PITCH         TOKEN AVG
1:               a    10 Measurement 1  11
2:               a    11 Measurement 2  11
3:               a    12 Measurement 3  11
4:               i    15 Measurement 1  16
5:               i    16 Measurement 2  16
6:               i    17 Measurement 3  16
```

Which looks easier to plot/manipulate

Comment: Huh, that's neat. Thanks for the suggestion. +1, though, ultimately I want to plot this using TOKEN as a group, so it's not too helpful to have it inline.

Comment: You can use this data structure to plot using `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, here is the `dplyr` + `ggplot2` solution

```
library(dplyr)
data2 = data %.%
  group_by(VOWEL_QUALITIES) %.%
  mutate(AVG = mean(PITCH))

library(ggplot2)
qplot(VOWEL_QUALITIES, PITCH, data = data2) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = AVG), color = 'red')
```

[image]